# Funds available for my stay (CAD)

Tags: visas, canada, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am planning to travel to Canada for 3 weeks for tourism with my wife and son (infant).
I am the family representative and applying for the visa for 3 of us. In the 'funds available for my stay (CAD)' field, should I divide the total funds in 3 applications, or should I mention the total funds available same in all the applications?
E.g. if I have $18000 funds available with me, should I divide $6000 in each application, or do I fill $18000 in all 3 applications?

Comment: I do not knkw for sure, but i would be inclined to mention the whole amount and then note that this is to be used to pay for the entire family.

Comment: I don't expect you to have too much trouble whichever way you decide to.

Comment: AFAIUI, a separate form is required for each of you, including the infant. I suggest dividing the amount in 2 and showing it for you and your wife only.

Answer (score 2):

It might be better to indicate the total amount available, as you'll also list those with whom you'll travel. While you will be travelling together, you'll file three, separate forms (IMM 5257), one for each of the adults, and one on behalf of your minor child (which you will sign). However, both you and your wife will also fill in the the Family Information form (IMM 5645); it makes it clear that you are a family, entering Canada and that there are shared expenses (e.g., accommodation). You can submit all family member applications in the same envelope with one payment receipt for the total fee for all of your applications.